# Why does retrieving data from Firebase work in an Interface but not in a method inside the Activity?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was looking for a way to retrieve data from Firebase. I realized I was doing it wrong all along since Firebase uses asynchronous tasks to get the data from the server. Every answer I stumbled upon uses an Interface to get said data and save them on local or global variables. What I'm not sure is why can't the same thing apply to a method in an Activity? Why **must** I use an Interface?

Comment: what exactly you want?

Comment: what I want is to get data and save it to global variables in my Activity. I know how it is done (via an Interface). What I wanna know is why this is the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have seen Interface everywhere because these calls are asynchronous as you also already aware of those, these interfaces are like callback which will be triggered when the fetching of data from firebase is done, so you will get a chance to do your work.

These cannot be a simple getter because this is a long-running task and you don't want to wait for your code for the response but you want to get notified when the data is ready to be used, hence the interface.

Comment: what if I want to wait for it to retrieve the data and after that do anything else?

Comment: by waiting you mean you want to block the UI thread and make your app ANR?

Comment: I mean I want the Activity to not do anything until I retrieve the data. So if what you suggest works, then sure.

Comment: you can show the progress bar, till you are fetching the data, firebase is designed to be asynchronous in nature.